# Is it possible to turn off buttons light on Lumia 920?

Tags: apps, settings, nokia-lumia-920, display

When i watch movies on my phone in the dark, the three buttons light up and are disturbing my view. Is there any way to turn them off? or an app that do this for me?

I have read that if you lock the screen and unlock it again, they should turn off. But that dosent work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to Settings -> Battery Saver -> and turn Battery Saver on the buttons will turn off.

We need to be sure you are in the conserve mode by going to "advanced" and select "always (not recommended)".

The problem is that you phone will not automatically sync with this option in place (you can see a litle heart in the battery icon). But you can sync manually.

Comment: Great answer, I have used Battery Saver quite a bit and have never noticed that happening!

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it is possible to turn them off, because there is [a feature suggestion for exactly this](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3367748-turn-off-lit-windows-button-when-watching-movie-lu) at the Windows Phone forum - which really should have been sent to Nokia feedback.